# Execute detect (with data tags)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to change a blockdata as an entity (ArmorStand, but at his x y and z)
it doesn't work! Any solutions?

```
/execute @e ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ minecraft:dropper 0 {Items:[0:{Slot:4b,id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b,Damage:0s}],id:"Dropper"} /blockdata ~ ~ ~ {......}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Execute can only used with entities. Use /testforblock and Chain Command Block instead.